# VSCode: How can I execute an arbitrary task using the JavaScript API?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

In newer versions of VSCode I can create bindings to any task I define in `tasks.json`. For example, with the 3 tasks below

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Clean",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "clean.cmd",
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
      "label": "Build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "build.cmd",
      "problemMatcher": [],
      "group": { "kind": "build", "isDefault": true }
    },
    {
      "label": "Flash",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "flash.cmd",
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I can create key bindings with

```json
[
  {
    "key": "alt+f9",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Clean"
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+f9",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.build"
  },
  {
    "key": "f9",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Flash"
  }
]
```

and everything works as expected. I am trying to do the same thing from within an extension (for example with [Script Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vs-script-commands)) using the VSCode API but it works only for the `build` and `test` tasks.

Calling

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.tasks.build")
```

works but

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.tasks.runTask", ["Clean"])
```

opens the task selection list.

How could I directly start other tasks beyond `build` and `test` using JavaScript code?

Answer (score 0):

Your tasks config file looks old. If you're using a new version of Visual Studio Code then you should upgrade.

I think the api is expecting the task to have a "label" field.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_convert-from-010-to-200

So intsead of:

```
{
   "taskName": "Clean",
   "type": "shell",
   "command": "clean.cmd",
   "problemMatcher": []
},
```

It should be:

```
{
  "label": "Clean",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "clean.cmd",
  "problemMatcher": []
},
```

Update: Try invoking it with just the string instead of wrapping it in an Array like this:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.tasks.runTask", "Clean")
```

Comment: I have upgraded but it does not affect my problem.`label` or `taskName` (which it is still supported), I can run the tasks from the UI but not using the JavaScript API. Nevertheless your answer reminded me to update the question. Thanks.